# About a tangent line on the curve

Tags: geogebra

The curve is given by `xy^3+2y-x^2+3x=-2`. If `y` is differentiable with respect to `x` then the slope of the tangent line at the point `(x_1,y_1)` is given by `m=y'(x_1)` so that the equation of this tangent line is `y-y_1=m(x-x_1)`.

For instance, if `(x_1,y_1)=(2,-1)` then I was able to compute manually that the tangent line is $-x+4y=-6$. When I tried to solve the problem using GeoGebra, there were two answers provided by GeoGebra. Of course, happy to see that one of the two answers is `-x+4y=-6`. Now, what made me distracted is the other answer given by `1.58x-1.99x=5.14`. I really do not know the idea behind this answer.

[image]

Well, I tried to think that `x` is a differentiable with respect to `y` and started solving for `x'(y)` implicitly but unfortunately not able to get the answer `1.58x -1.99y=5.14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curve is not a function, but an *implicit curve*. This means you are using this overload of the [`Tangent`](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Tangent_Command) command:

> ### Tangent( <Point>, <Implicit Curve> )
>
> Creates the tangent to the implicit curve in the given point.
>
> > Example: `Tangent((1,1), x^2+y^2=1))` yields lines *x=1* and *y=1*.

Although it is not super clear from that description, GeoGebra generates all tangents *passing through* the given point, not just the tangent *at* that point (the example provided does support that).

This behavior is more appearent when the point is not on the curve:

[image]

So, the other solution you see is actually the tangent at around x=3.98.

These tangents can be given by the equation of a line [image: $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$], but with m=y'(x), instead of m=y'(x_0).

Differentiating yields

[image: $$y'(x) = \frac{-3 + 2 x - y^3}{2 + 3 x y^2}$$].

Then solving the system of equations

[image: $$y+1=\frac{-3 + 2 x - y^3}{2 + 3 x y^2}(x-2)\ xy^3+2y-x^2+3x=-2$$]

...does indeed result in x=2 and x=3.98651